# Create comma delimited string array from a column in excel to use in VBA sql query

Tags: sql, arrays, excel, vba, csv

I need to get values from Sheet1 Column A (number of rows changes every day - can be more than 7,000) and Sheet2 Column B (also dynamic - changes every day), put those values from the columns into an array in STRING type (can be two arrays as long as I can use them in the query) and use the array in vba query WHERE ... IN ('array') to be run in MS-SQL server.

I've tried different ways to get the values into an array but have failed as many solutions offered need to use Array AS Variant when I need String type (to work in the query). One method that kind of worked was getting the values (comma separated) into one cell in another sheet and using that cell.value in the query. But that method is only good for total rows of 3000 or less. I've tried adding more - like cell2.value, cell3.value, but I would get errors (ex)if there were no values available for cell3.value. Please help.

```
Sub GetData()

Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim mssql As String
Dim row As Integer
Dim Col As Integer
Dim WB As ThisWorkbook

'============THIS IS THE PART I NEED HELP WITH ======================
Dim strArray() As String    'TRYING TO GET VALUES FROM COLUMN AS ARRAY
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim i As Long

TotalRows = Rows(Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    ReDim strArray(1 To TotalRows)

    For i = 1 To TotalRows
        strArray(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value & "','"    'TRYING TO INCLUDE COMMAS BETWEEN VALUES
    Next
'===========================================================================  
        
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection      'NEED TO CONNECT TO SQL SERVER TO RUN QUERY
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
mssql = "SELECT Order.ID, Order.OrderDate, Order.Account" _
        & " FROM dbo.tbl_Order" _
        & " WHERE Order.ID IN ('" & strArray() & "0'")"   '<=== THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO INSERT STRING ARRAY
        
        
    oConn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};" & _
    "server=SERVER01;authenticateduser = TRUE;database=DATABASE01"
            
    oConn.ConnectionTimeout = 30
        oConn.Open
rs.Open mssql, oConn
If rs.EOF Then
MsgBox "No matching records found."
rs.Close
oConn.Close
Exit Sub
End If

' ===clear data in columns in worksheet as new values are copied over old ones
' ===this part is working fine
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A:P").ClearContents

' START WRITING DATA TO SHEET3
row = 5
Col = 1

    For Each fld In rs.Fields
    Sheet3.Cells(row, Col).Value = fld.Name
    Col = Col + 1
    Next
    
rs.MoveFirst

row = row + 1

Do While Not rs.EOF

Col = 1
    
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
    Sheet1.Cells(row, Col).Value = fld
    Col = Col + 1
    Next
row = row + 1
rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close

oConn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to build an array but rather a string with the values you need.  I stripped down your code to illustrate how this works:

```
Sub GetData()
   Dim values As String
   Dim mssql As String
   Dim TotalRows As Long
   Dim i As Long
   
   TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

   For i = 1 To TotalRows
      values = values & "'" & Cells(i, 1).Value & "',"
   Next
   
   values = Mid(values, 1, Len(values) - 1)
   
   mssql = "SELECT Order.ID, Order.OrderDate, Order.Account " & _
           "FROM dbo.tbl_Order " & _
           "WHERE Order.ID IN (" & values & ")"

   MsgBox mssql
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Get Zero-Based From Column

- If you can use an array of strings (don't know `SQL`), for column `A` you could e.g. use:

  ```
  Dim strArray() As String: strArray = getZeroBasedFromColumn(Range("A2"))
  ```
- If you have to use a string then you will have to do:

  ```
  Dim strArray As String
  strArray = "'" & Join(getZeroBasedFromColumn(Range("A2")), "','") & "'"
  ```

  and use `strArray` without the parentheses.
- Qualify the first cell range (`A2`) appropriately e.g. `WB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")`.
- Both solutions use the following function.

**The Code**

```
Function getZeroBasedFromColumn( _
    FirstCell As Range) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "getZeroBasedFromColumn"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not FirstCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim rg As Range
        Set rg = FirstCell.Resize(FirstCell.Worksheet.Rows.Count - FirstCell.Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not rg Is Nothing Then
            Set rg = FirstCell.Resize(rg.Row - FirstCell.Row + 1)
            Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
            Dim Data As Variant
            If rCount = 1 Then
                ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
            Else
                Data = rg.Value
            End If
            Dim arr() As String: ReDim arr(0 To rCount - 1)
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 1 To rCount
                arr(i - 1) = CStr(Data(i, 1))
            Next i
            getZeroBasedFromColumn = arr
        End If
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Sub getZeroBasedFromColumnTEST()
    Dim arr() As String: arr = getZeroBasedFromColumn(Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (if you have the necessary database permissions) is to create a temporary table and use a JOIN in place of the WHERE IN().

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()
 
    ' get list of order numbers from Col A Sheet1 and COl B Sheet2
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range
    Dim ar, ar1, ar2, iLastRow As Long, SQL As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, id As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")
 
    ' copy sheet1 Column A into array ar1
    iLastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    Set rngA = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & iLastRow)
    If rngA.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        ar1 = Array(0, rngA.Cells(1, 1).Value2)
    Else
        ar1 = Application.Transpose(rngA.Value2)
    End If
    'Debug.Print "A", LBound(ar1), UBound(ar1)

    ' copy sheet2 column B into array ar2
    iLastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
    Set rngB = Sheet2.Range("B1:B" & iLastRow)
    If rngB.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        ar2 = Array(0, rngB.Cells(1, 1).Value2)
    Else
        ar2 = Application.Transpose(rngB.Value2)
    End If
    'Debug.Print "B", LBound(ar2), UBound(ar2)

    ' connect to DB and create temporary table
    Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
    With oConn
        .ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};" & _
         "server=SERVER01;authenticateduser = TRUE;database=DATABASE01"
        .ConnectionTimeout = 30
        .Open
    End With

    oConn.Execute "CREATE TABLE #tmp (ID varchar(20) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (ID ASC))"
    
    ' prepare insert query
    SQL = "INSERT INTO #tmp (ID) VALUES (?)"
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .ActiveConnection = oConn
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20)
    End With
    
    ' insert array values into temp table
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    For Each ar In Array(ar1, ar2)
        oConn.BeginTrans
        For i = 1 To UBound(ar)
            id = Trim(ar(i))
            If Len(id) > 0 Then
                cmd.Execute n, id
            End If
        Next
        oConn.CommitTrans
        'Debug.Print i - 1 & " Inserted"
    Next
    n = oConn.Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmp")(0)
    'Debug.Print n & " records inserted into #tmp in " & Format(Timer - t0, "#.0 secs")

    ' select records using join as where filter
    SQL = " SELECT Ord.ID, Ord.OrderDate, Ord.Account" _
        & " FROM [tbl_Order] as Ord" _
        & " JOIN #tmp ON Ord.ID = #tmp.ID"
    
    ' output result
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = oConn.Execute(SQL, n)
    wsOut.Range("A:P").ClearContents
    
    ' header
    Dim fld, cell As Range
    Set cell = wsOut.Cells(5, 1)
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        cell = fld.Name
        Set cell = cell.Offset(0, 1)
    Next
    
    ' data
    wsOut.Cells(6, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    oConn.Close
   
    ' end
    n = wsOut.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row - 6
    MsgBox n & " rows witten in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.00 secs")
    
End Sub
```